# How to access data in Bloc's state from another bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am developing a Flutter application using Bloc pattern. After success authentication, UserSate has User object. In all other Blocs, I need to access User object in UserState. I tried with getting UserBloc on other Bloc's constructor parameters and accessing User object. But it shows that User object is null. Anyone have a better solution?

```
class SectorHomeBloc extends Bloc<SectorHomeEvent, SectorHomeState> {
  final OutletRepository outletRepository;
  UserBloc userBloc;
  final ProductRepository productRepository;
  final ProductSubCategoryRepository productSubCategoryRepository;
  final PromotionRepository promotionRepository;
  final ProductMainCategoryRepository mainCategoryRepository;

  SectorHomeBloc({
    @required this.outletRepository,
    @required this.userBloc,
    @required this.productSubCategoryRepository,
    @required this.productRepository,
    @required this.promotionRepository,
    @required this.mainCategoryRepository,
  });
  @override
  SectorHomeState get initialState => SectorHomeLoadingState();

  @override
  Stream<SectorHomeState> mapEventToState(SectorHomeEvent event) async* {
    try {
      print(userBloc.state.toString());
      LatLng _location = LatLng(
          userBloc.state.user.defaultLocation.coordinate.latitude,
          userBloc.state.user.defaultLocation.coordinate.longitude);
      String _token = userBloc.state.user.token;

      if (event is GetAllDataEvent) {
        yield SectorHomeLoadingState();
        List<Outlet> _previousOrderedOutlets =
            await outletRepository.getPreviousOrderedOutlets(
                _token, _location, event.orderType, event.sectorId);

        List<Outlet> _featuredOutlets =
            await outletRepository.getFeaturedOutlets(
                _token, _location, event.orderType, event.sectorId);
        List<Outlet> _nearestOutlets = await outletRepository.getOutletsNearYou(
            _token, _location, event.orderType, event.sectorId);

        List<Product> _newProducts = await productRepository.getNewItems(
            _token, _location, event.orderType, event.sectorId);

        List<Product> _trendingProducts =
            await productRepository.getTrendingItems(
                _token, _location, event.orderType, event.sectorId);

        List<Promotion> _promotions = await promotionRepository
            .getVendorPromotions(_token, event.sectorId);
        yield SectorHomeState(
          previousOrderedOutlets: _previousOrderedOutlets,
          featuredOutlets: _featuredOutlets,
          nearByOutlets: _nearestOutlets,
          newItems: _newProducts,
          trendingItems: _trendingProducts,
          promotions: _promotions,
        );
      }
    } on SocketException {
      yield SectorHomeLoadingErrorState('could not connect to server');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      yield SectorHomeLoadingErrorState('Error');
    }
  }
}
```

The print statement [print(userBloc.state.toString());] in mapEventToState method shows the initial state of UserSate.
But, at the time of this code executing UserState is in UserLoggedInState.

Comment: actually you are trying to access a class property from another class right?

Comment: At first define User object member variable in event 'GetAllDataEvent' class. And pass the user object by calingl 'add(GetAllDataEvent(user: userObj))' in the state where UserBloc is loaded. And get a user object by calling 'event.user' in 'if (event is GetAllDataEvent)'

Comment: thank you so much. its working. but there is another official way to communicate between Blocs. by the way, thanks a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UPDATE (Best Practice):
please refer to the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72528313/6896271)
so the best way for that is to hear the changes of another bloc inside the widget you are in, and fire the event based on that.
so what you will do is wrap your widget in a bloc listener and listen to the bloc you want.

```
    class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocListener<FirstBloc, FirstBlocState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
             if(state is StateFromFirstBloc){
             BlocProvider.of<SecondBloc>(context).add(SecondBlocEvent());}//or whatever you want
          },
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child:   Text('THIS IS NEW SCREEN'),
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<SecondBloC>(context).add(SecondBloCEvent());
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

the lovely thing about listener is that you can listen anywhere to any bloc and do whatever you want
here is the [official documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication) for it

OLD WAY (NOT Recommended)

there is an official way to do this as in the documentation, called [Bloc-to-Bloc Communication](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication)
and here is the example for this as in the documentation

```
class MyBloc extends Bloc {
  final OtherBloc otherBloc;
  StreamSubscription otherBlocSubscription;

  MyBloc(this.otherBloc) {
    otherBlocSubscription = otherBloc.listen((state) {
        // React to state changes here.
        // Add events here to trigger changes in MyBloc.
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    otherBlocSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

sorry for the late update for this answer and thanks to @MJ studio

Comment: most  Welcome buddy!.

Comment: The correct way is actually: otherBloc.stream.listen((state) {})

Comment: The documentation literate advises to NOT do that. It's better to use the two other solutions described below that part.

Comment: This is perfectly misunderstanding what the docs say...

Comment: may you please explain more @MJStudio

Comment: In your link, the document says about the bloc has another bloc as a dependency like the following. 

***Because blocs expose streams, it may be tempting to make a bloc which listens to another bloc. You should not do this. There are better alternatives than resorting to the code below:***

So, the docs guides do not following this way.
Instead, presentation layer communication or domain layer communication is encouraged

Comment: got it thanks @MJStudio, I'll update the answer based on that

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer actually has a comment in the above example in the official docs saying "No matter how much you are tempted to do this, you should not do this! Keep reading for better alternatives!"!!!

Here's the official doc link, ultimately one bloc should not know about any other blocs, add methods to update your bloc and these can be triggered from blocListeners which listen to changes in your other blocs: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=connecting-blocs-through-domain

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<WeatherCubit, WeatherState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // When the first bloc's state changes, this will be called.
        //
        // Now we can add an event to the second bloc without it having
        // to know about the first bloc.
        BlocProvider.of<SecondBloc>(context).add(SecondBlocEvent());
      },
      child: TextButton(
        child: const Text('Hello'),
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<FirstBloc>(context).add(FirstBlocEvent());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```