# Is there a way to passing data between blocs or cubits in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm working with Flutter quite a long time and  I had a problem to passing data between two cubit .
Is there a way to passing data between blocs or cubits in flutter ?

Comment: I found this video on Bloc to Bloc communication to be excellent: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ricBLKHeubM

Comment: Have you checked the [official documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication)?

Comment: you can check this answer [Passing data from bloc to bloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64482468/how-to-access-data-in-blocs-state-from-another-bloc/64494653#64494653)